# Checking Python check failing WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I have an installer file in which I am checking if the python is installed on the machine or not by checking the registry entry. During testing the same, observed an issue in which the python is not installed on the system. Still, the registry entry for the python is not giving error.

```
<Property Id='CHECK_PYTHON'>
  <RegistrySearch Id='SearchPyInCU'
              Root='HKCU'
              Key='SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.6'
              Name='Version'
              Type= "raw"
              Win64="yes"/>
  <RegistrySearch Id='SearchPyInLM'
        Root='HKLM'
        Key='SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.6'
        Name='Version'
        Type='raw'
        Win64="yes"/>
  <RegistrySearch Id='SearchPyInWoW64'
   Root='HKLM'
   Key='SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\3.6'
   Name='Version'
   Type='raw'/>
</Property>
```

On checking found that the registry entry for the python version is still there in the local machine not sure if it is there because of some error during uninstall. However, the default value is blank.

Is there any better way to check if the system has python installed or not?

One option which I can think of using custom action and running the python -v command and checking if it returns an error or not. But I want first to explore some other options.

Comment: Did you try to search for the main Python executable? You can search the local system for files and specify a mask to detect only certain versions of a file with a given name. Would this suffice? This is the built in AppSearch feature of MSI (very limited for ini-files, but seems to work OK for other file types - in terms of detecting if they are present or not). Maybe there are built-in features in Python you can call to determine if the installation is actually working as well? Python is unchartered territory for me.

Comment: All you are doing is setting a property (`CHECK_PYTHON`), not doing anything that will or won't generate any error, in the code you've shared. What are you doing with that property elsewhere in your authoring?

Comment: Looking at a verbose log, what value does that property get when Python is installed vs what value does it contain when Python isn't installed?

Comment: Hi, Stein, I will try the App search Hi Murri after checking the registry search there is condition based on the check_python property to give the user an alert and abort the installation. But as the registry entry is still there even though Python is uninstalled from the system (not sure why) the property check is not giving the alert